# building simple Android camera app on Eclipse :cannot identify "preview"

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-layout

I'm trying to build  a simple camera app (from the java2s.com website) on Elipse.
This is the first part of the code:
package com.example.appprev;

```
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class PreviewActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {


  Camera mCamera;
    SurfaceView mPreview;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mPreview = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.preview);
        mPreview.getHolder().addCallback(this);
        mPreview.getHolder().setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        mCamera = Camera.open();
    }

etc.etc.

and the xml main is:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <SurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/preview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  />
</RelativeLayout>
```

There is an error message near the first mPreview line: "Preview cannot be resolved."

Also an error message near the Public Class line(PreviewActivity must be defined in it's own file)

Perhaps the main xml was loaded incorrectly?
I clicked on NEW ADD xml file and added the "main" file in the layout folder.
I'm new to android and Elipse  thanks for any advice  Dave.

Answer (score 0):

> PreviewActivity must be defined in it's own file

this means, well, what it is literally.

This class should be in a file called `PreviewActivity.java`, preferably it is the only public class in the file.

As for "Preview cannot be resolved", it is a problem with your java code, not xml. May I confirm it is "**Preview** cannot be resolved", or "**mPreview** cannot be resolved"? It seems like it is the later one. You don't have any variable named "Preview" within the code you posted. Could you please confirm that?

Comment: the message is: "preview cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: The same message appeared near the R.layout.main line until I installed the xml main file.

Comment: May I ask what do you mean by "installed the xml main file"? Wasn't 'main.xml' there at the first place?

Comment: There was R.layout.activity_main but no R.activity.main